# Which Project Management Software is adequate for Software & Non-Software Projects?

Tags: project-management, collaboration, time-management, tracker

**PMS = (Project Management Software)**

I used trac for software development some time ago. Right now I'm searching for a new more powerful (scheduling, gantt charts, ...) free solution (as in free beer ;-) and free to install on my server) for my current software project.

Besides the current software project, abstract project management features like issue-tracking & scheduling would be great for coordinating a group of volunteers for real-life projects as well. I would want one solution for both purposes, so that I have the hassle of installation, getting used to the system and administration only once.

So I tried redmine but the problem is it seems to be designed for software projects only. I can't suggest such a solution for the volunteer-group if tickets/issues would have to be of type bug, feature, ...

I shortlisted the following six PMS from the [wikipedia comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_project_management_software):

- Project.net
- Project-Open
- Redmine
- Trac
- Endeavour Software Project Management
- eGroupWare

I guess they are all more or less fine for software development but would you consider any of these to be good for the non-software project as well?

**Cliff Notes:**

I would want a start page situation like in trac.
The start-page is a wiki presenting the project and not the PMS. But you can log into the PMS from there.

*Feature-wish list*: wiki, Issue tracking, revision control, scheduling & gantt charts, forums (least important)
(Btw: I'm very aware that I can't expect everything to be perfect ;-)

1. Do you know a suitable solution for software and real-life projects or a highly customizable PMS where I can easily remove sth. like "browse source"(trac) and rename things like ticket/issue-types "bug", "feature"?
2. Any experience good/bad with the above mentioned six PMS? 
   I would personally guess that "Redmine" and "Endeavour Software Project Management" are too focused on software projects.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at project kaiser (http://www.projectkaiser.com). It's a web-based project management and issue tracking software, with Gantt, wikis and forums included. Successfully used in both software and non-software projects.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try setting up different "trackers" and workflows in Redmine.  You should be able to name these different processes in non-software language.  If you're willing to edit a little code, you can also change the labels on a lot of things pretty easily.  E.g., Version becomes Milestone.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but  
1) How would I go for that? (IOW where to edit?) 
2) Would I be able to have one project that uses "software language" and one that uses "non-software language" for the same redmine installation?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the IT derivative of our project management portal product (free open source version is available) http://yoxel.com/project-management-portal.html

For non-software projects I think email could work pretty well, and here is a new product we're working on that makes the email collaboration experience more suitable for project management: yoxel.com/personal-commitment-manager.html

Comment: Email works well until a certain size project, number of issues or number of active people are involved. Email also lacks straigh forward seaching, reporting etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a core contributor to [web2project](http://web2project.net/) and most of our users are *not* software people at all. In fact, it appears that law firms and contractors (as in the building construction type) are nearly 80% of our installed based on surveys.

In our case, everything revolves around the concept of a Project - tasks, files, forums, helpdesk tickets, even risks - and is treated that way.